# Retrieve data from an HD with vmfs partition

Tags: data-recovery, vmfs, partition-table

My problem is the following:

I have a 1TB HDD with the information of a server that I need now.

I do not know what to do to access the information, inside the HDD there is a `vmfs` formatted partition that I do not see, and it contains the data I need.

I think the problem is in the final limit of partition number 3, but as I say, I do not know what the problem is.

I appreciate any help.

**fdisk -l**
[image: fdisk -l]

**gdisk -l /dev/sdb**
[image: gdisk -l /dev/sdb]

**Info partition gdisk**
[image: Info partition gdisk]

[image: Info partition 1 - 5]

[image: Info partition 6 - 8]

Comment: Your 1 TB drive has a partition claiming to be 2 TB in size. Something went very wrong before today. It is possible that your data is lost. Consider going to your backups.

Answer (score 0):

vmfs filesystem is vmware filesytem.
It seems that you need to install a vmfs tool to read vmfs from ubuntu, then mount the partition on your ubuntu.

download the package:
`sudo apt install vmfs-tool`s (or apt-get install vmfs-tools on older versions)

create the folder where to mount the fs:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/vmfs
```

mount  the fs:

```
vmfs-fuse /dev/sdb3 mnt/vmfs
```

you can use lsblk to verify it's sdb3.

edit: I didn't test it so it may need something else, but it may help to copy and save the data elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks, but that did not work. That worked for me on another HDD that had a vmfs partition, but this disk does not have a partition with this format. **Result**
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHhpp.png)